# Full calendar: improve event fetching speed

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization, fullcalendar

I am using Arshaw's Full Calendar plugin as part of my application. With more and more users where users can see events created by not just themselves but everyone else as well, I am running into issues to excessively long wait times.

This is how my event's are loaded in to Full Calendar:

```
...
eventSources: [
{
    url: 'calendar.php?page=fetchevents',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        emp_id: employee
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('There was an error fetching appointments. Please click OK and then refresh the page.');
    }
}
],
...
```

This is what `calendar.php?page=fetchevents` returns:

```
$events = $cal -> listEvents($_POST['emp_id']);

//A few simple if/else statements

foreach ($events as $e){
        $event_array[] = array(
            'id' => $e['event_id'],
            'parent_event_id' => $e['parent_event_id'],
            'emp_id' => $e['emp_id'],
            'last_modified' => $e['last_modified'],
            'lm_fname' => $e['lm_fname'],
            'lm_lname' => $e['lm_lname'],
            'updated_on' => date('j F @ H:i',strtotime($e['updated_on'])),
            ****'creator' => $cal -> getCreator($e['event_id']),
            ****'invited' => getInvitees($e['event_id']),
            ****'creator_alt' => $cal -> getCreator($e['parent_event_id']),
            ****'invited_alt' => $cal -> getInvitees($e['parent_event_id']),
            'cfname' => $e['first_name'],
            'clname' => $e['last_name'],
            'title' => $e['appointment_type'],
            'start' => $e['appointment_start'],
            'end' => $e['appointment_end'],
            'className' => $category,
            'description' => $e['appointment_description'],
            'sname' => $e['st_fname'].' '.$e['st_lname'],
            'snumber' => $e['student'],
            'estatus' => $e['appointment_status'],
            'arrivalstatus' => $e['student_arrival_status'],
            'allDay' => false,
            'color' => $second_color,
            'textcolor' => $text_color,
            'borderColor' => "white"
        );
}
echo json_encode($event_array);
```

Thee four array properties starting with `****` above are get their values from SQL queries. Without those 4 properties, **approximately 800 events take an average of 2.5 seconds** to be displayed. If I add those 4 lines back in, **the same events take an average of 17 seconds to display**.

Separately, each of the those lines are equally slow i.e. if I am removed one at a time, **I'd get about a 4 second improvement** each time.

So I then started to look at the SQL for those queries. For example, `getCreator()` is as follows:

```
SELECT z.first_name, z.last_name
  FROM calendar x
  JOIN users z
    ON x.emp_id = z.user_id
 WHERE x.event_id= $id
```

The table `calendar` has `event_id` as the primary key and `parent_event_id` has an index on it. I cannot think of anything else to do to the query above to make it better.

The four lines that are causing the delay above can be removed completely and then fetched one at a time when a user wants to see details for a given event. However, I was wondering if I can make any adjustments to the table itself or to the SQL to minimize the issue?

Any suggestions are welcome.

---

Edit 1: code for function `listEvents()`:

```
SELECT x.*, z.*, s.first_name AS st_fname, s.last_name AS st_lname, l.first_name AS lm_fname, l.last_name AS lm_lname
              FROM calendar x
        RIGHT JOIN users z
                ON x.emp_id = z.user_id
        RIGHT JOIN users l
                ON x.last_modified = l.user_id
         LEFT JOIN students s
                ON x.student=s.student_id
             WHERE z.department= '3'
```

Comment: You'd have to fundamentally alter your code. You're doing what looks to be 4 completely independent DB calls, which could be reduced to two with (hoepfully) relative easy by simply having a single `getCreatorAndInvitees()` type logic behind the scenes. And if those creators and/or invitees can show up multiple times, you can eliminate entire db calls by caching the results from previous queries.

Comment: Are you querying the database during each iteration in the foreach loop or are the db results stored in a variable before you start your foreach?

Comment: @RossWilson I am query the database each time in the foreach. So for 800 events, it is running 800*4 = 3600 queries within the foreach.

Comment: Could you also show me the query you are using inside your `listEvents()` function?

Comment: @RossWilson I have edited the question to include this

Comment: @MarcB I cannot combine `getCreator()` and `getInvitees()` because they have different `WHERE` clauses. Also, creators and invitees vary largely from event to event, so I don't know how much I can gain from caching.

Comment: I have gotten a slight improvement in speed by upgrading my PHP version to allow for the use of native `json_encode`

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code you should have the results for `getCreator()` in your query inside `listEvents`.

So, I would look at your code for `listEvents()` and simply add another array element to your array when processing your result set.

**Note** You should always try and avoid calling a DB inside a loop! Either create a second query and store the results in a variable before hand, or use an extra JOIN to get more results from your original query (depending on a few factors).

I hope this helps